# Django - display Json or Httpresponse in template

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, httpresponse

I have something this in views.py:

```
return JsonResponse({'foo': 'bar'})
```

How would i display "bar" in the template? Something like:

```
   <h1 id="demo"></h1>
    <script>
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ?JsonResponse?;
    </script>
```

or could it be done with http response?

```
 return HttpResponse("Bar")
```

and html:

```
<h1 id="demo"></h1>
    <script>
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ?HttpResponse?;
    </script>
```

Comment: Are you making an Ajax request to the URL/View that are returning the JsonReponse? Or, do you want to simply pass JSON content from a view to a template?

Comment: @teewuane  I just want to pass JSON content from a view to a template.

Comment: Why don't use this? <h1 id="demo">{{foo}}</h1>

Comment: I want to pass in text without having to refresh, because the json would get passed after form validattion of modal

Comment: @MannymAnn I'm pretty confused. Will you describe the workflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Let's assume you have a url `/yourURL` connected to a view function. Let's call this function index:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def index(request):
    data = {foo:'bar'}
    render(request,'path/to/yourTemplate.html',data)
```

I use `render` as a shortcut. In yourTemplate.html, you can access the data as `{{foo}}` anywhere. For sending json objects to the template without rendering, consider the following template (yourTemplate.html):

```
<div id='initialData'>{{foo}}</div>
<div id='jsondata'></div>
```

You need a new view and an ajax request to grab information from it. You can do this in the same index view, or you can build a brand new url and associated view. Let's use the second option. It goes like this, you build a new URL `/yourURL/download` connected to a `download` view (views.py):

```
def download(request):
   data = {foo2:'bar2'}
   JsonResponse(data)
```

Then you need an ajax request to call this view and write the response on the div on success (yourTemplate.html):

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: "/yourURL/download",
    type: 'get',
    success: function (data) {
      alert("Success");
      var div = document.getElementById('jsondata');
      div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + data.foo;       

    }
  });
 </script>
```

Voila! You will have both bar and bar2 in your screen. To elaborate further you need a button associated with the ajax call, so you can see that the page actually does not render again with the JsonResponse.